# MySQL: Can I index a datetime field? MySQL won't do it

Tags: mysql, indexing

```
mysql> create index index_questions_on_publishedAt on questions(publishedAt);
ERROR 1317 (70100): Query execution was interrupted
mysql> select count(*) from questions;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|   491773 | 
+----------+
1 row in set (1.02 sec)

# Is it even reasonable for this query to take 1 second?

mysql> select count(*) from questions where publishedAt <= '2011-08-23 19:52:01' and publishedAt >= '2011-08-23 19:49:44';
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|       30 | 
+----------+
1 row in set (0.71 sec)

MySQL info: Server version: 5.1.41-3ubuntu12.10 (Ubuntu)
```

Most of my queries test for varying time ranges, and the contents of each range are
in constant flux, so I can't cache much here.  Patiently awaiting any advice... Thanks.

Comment: Adding an index causes the index to be populated. You've got almost a half million records, it'll take more than zero-time to build the index. MyISAM `count(*)` queries are fast, as the row count is stored in the table metadata. InnODB `count(*)` are relatively slow, as it has to scan the table (can't keep a single row count somewhere, because transactions will make it inaccurate).

Comment: Do you have a cleanup script running separately? That error code shows up when a query is killed via `kill` from another mysql session. it could be seeing the alter table command as a runaway process and killing it.

Comment: FYI: count(*) is only slower on InnoDB when no condition is used. If a WHERE clause is specified, both InnoDB and MyISAM should be about the same.

Answer (score 2):

I have a table with 725K records, and here are my results:

- Before creating an index:
- - Counting with a condition with no index: 0.59 seconds
- - Counting with no condition: 0.8 seconds
- Creating an index on a datetime field: 2.28 seconds
- - Counting with condition: 0.07 seconds

Hope that answers your question.

Your index creation does seem to be getting interrupted by something or someone, but I would double-check the log files to see if there's anything going on there.